# Kendo UI Grid - Excel Export with hidden columns and custom formatting

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-grid

I'm attempting to use the Grid component's built-in support for exporting to excel, applying custom cell formatting as shown in these Telerik docs:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/excel/cell-format

The approach using hard-coded row / cell indexes in the export comes with a rather obvious issue when exporting a grid with a prior hidden column displayed - best way to reproduce is to refer to this jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/3anqpnqt/1/

1. Run fiddle
2. Click export to excel - observe custom number formatting
3. Unhide subcategory column (using column menu)
4. Click export to excel - observe custom number formatting on column 2 which is now 'subcategory'

With reference to this code in the fiddle:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    toolbar: ["excel"],
    excel: {
      fileName: "Grid.xlsx",
      filterable: true
    },
    columns: [
      { field: "productName" },
      { field: "category" },
      { field: "subcategory", hidden: true },
      { field: "unitPrice"}
    ],
    dataSource: [
      { productName: "Tea", category: "Beverages", subcategory: "Bev1", unitPrice: 1.5 },
      { productName: "Coffee", category: "Beverages", subcategory: "Bev2", unitPrice: 5.332 },
      { productName: "Ham", category: "Food", subcategory: "Food1", unitPrice: -2.3455 },
      { productName: "Bread", category: "Food", subcategory: "Food2", unitPrice: 6 }
    ],
    columnMenu: true,
    excelExport: function(e) {      
      var sheet = e.workbook.sheets[0];

      for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < sheet.rows.length; rowIndex++) {
        var row = sheet.rows[rowIndex];
        var numericFormat = "#,##0.00;[Red](#,##0.00);-";
        for (var cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < row.cells.length; cellIndex++) {
            var cell = row.cells[cellIndex];
            if (row.type === "data") {
                if (cellIndex == 2) { // how are we able to identify the column without using indexes?
                    cell.format = numericFormat;
                    cell.hAlign = "right";
                }
            }
        }      
      }      
    }
});
```

What I need to be able to do is identify the cell as the 'unitPrice' and apply the format, but inspection of the object model within the `excelExport` handler doesn't give me any way to make this link.  In my real application, I have several custom formats to apply (percentages, n0, n2 etc) so it's not as simple as going `$.isNumeric(cell.value)` or otherwise.

Update

I also need the solution to work with column / row groups, which generate additional header rows / columns in the Excel model.

Comment: I don't know if this link will help but I had to write my own parser and exporter to excel and pdf prior to official support. I think the column/row and recursive grouping in the underlying grid structure remains. If you can untangle my code from many years ago then you might spot the recursive relationship among groups and columns. -->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753051/having-difficulty-creating-an-array-of-json-objects-for-use-in-a-kendo-grid/25753400#25753400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like row[0] is the header row, so you could try changing

```
if (cellIndex == 2) {
```

to

```
if (sheet.rows[0].cells[cellIndex].value == "unitPrice") {
```

EDIT:

Seems to work with column group: https://jsfiddle.net/dwosrs0x/

Update:

The object model for worksheet is not the most clear. The first row does seem to be a "master" header row in the various scenarios that I looked at. Here is something that seems to work if unitPrice is not in a grouping. If unitPrice is in a grouping, then something more complicated involving the group header (row[1]) might be possible. The puzzle is to find out what position the desired column will eventually occupy.

```
var header = sheet.rows[0];
var upIndex = -1;
var upFound = false;

for (var cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < header.cells.length; cellIndex++) {

    if ('colSpan' in header.cells[cellIndex]) 
        upIndex = upIndex + header.cells[cellIndex].colSpan;
    else 
        upIndex = upIndex + 1;

    if (header.cells[cellIndex].value == "unitPrice") { // wot we want
        upFound = true;
        break;
    }
}

for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < sheet.rows.length; rowIndex++) {
    var row = sheet.rows[rowIndex];
    if (row.type === "data" && upFound) {
        var cell = row.cells[upIndex];
        cell.format = numericFormat;
        cell.hAlign = "right";
    }

}
```

fiddle with groups - https://jsfiddle.net/dwosrs0x/4/

fiddle with straightforward grid (to prove it still works) - https://jsfiddle.net/gde4nr0y/1/

This definitely has the whiff of "bodge" about it.

Comment: This is a nice idea, but I don't think it holds for grids that have column groups, and / or row groups (which I admit wasn't included in the original fiddle example).  Given a column group, an additional header row is included which includes merged / spanned cells, and, again, no clear way as to how to calculate the correct index.   Given a row group, an additional column is included in the excel model to create a 'blank' group column.  I'll update the question with these points, as I'm after a solution for all configurations.

Comment: @SteveChapman Seems to work with column group (see fiddle). I don't know how you are doing row groups. Perhaps you could illustrate with code.

Comment: See this example (which is an update of the fiddle you used) : https://jsfiddle.net/dwosrs0x/2/

Comment: @SteveChapman I feel your pain. Updated to (hopefully) work in the cases where unitPrice is not part of a column group. I daresay it could be expanded to cater for that scenario as well.

Comment: I appreciate the effort you've made here.  It is, as you say, a bit bodgy, but in the absence of some kind of DSL over the data / excel models, I think it's a workable solution.  Have raised as an issue with kendo as it can't be a problem limited to just me... I'll mark as correct, will revisit as an when any news arises.