# Kendo grid excel Export without applied options

Tags: excel, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using kendo Excel export. My requirement is not to export plain excel sheet with all the data in the kendo grid. Currently, kendo grid is applying the filters and adding the grouping rows if the user applies anything on the grid. I don't want any options to be exported. Just need plain excel sheet. Is there any easy to do it.

Thanks,

Narendra

Comment: This may be relevant --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35844063/kendo-ui-grid-excel-export-with-hidden-columns-and-custom-formatting

Comment: Is this for kendo angular2? If so, I may be able to answer it

Comment: Thanks. but, Solved it using Jquery already.